# Why can't I import Individual Prefixes into the database?

Tags: import

When importing, Induvidual Prefixes don't seem to "take" and apply.
Why is this, and how does one get around it?

Answer (score 4):

Why?, well I have no idea (sorry to dissapoint!)

How to get around - well, it would appear that civi requires the numeric Value (1,2,3), rather than the label (Mr, Mrs etc) for the option. To find the values for substitution one can go to:

> **administer > System Settings > Option Groups**

and hit the "options" link to the right of "Individual Contact Prefixes". The prefixes in your csv will need to be substituted with these values.

Hope that helps...

Comment: As of 4.6.14 Civi is looking for the label (e.g. 'Mr') , not the value.  But of course the matching has to be exact, as Aidan points out below

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the prefixes in the import exactly match the ones configured.
If you have "Mr." configured but the import has "Mr", the record is imported without error but the prefix is not set (as of 4.6.10)